# Should I list memberships that have expired on my resume

Tags: cv

I was a member of the [AMS](http://www.ams.org/home/page) in 2014, but my school had cut funding for 2015, should I still list I was a member in 2014 on my CV?

Comment: In my opinion, this information is not useful on CV in the first place. How does paying money to some organization make you a better mathematician?

Comment: @BorisBukh it shows interest and commitment to a lesser extent. It's fairly commonplace, as I've seen to include societies one is associated with to be listed on one's resume.

Comment: @BorisBukh it ultimately depends on what the organization is. For example, IEEE dues pay for magazines and typically provide you access to literature in the CS field.

Comment: I see no benefit in listing *expired* memberships - it only encourges people to wonder why you didn't pay to renew your membership when it expired. If you are a mathematics student, the more important question you should ask yourself is whether you should be an MAA member and list that on your vita - it depends on the type of school you are looking to apply to.

Answer (score 2):

When you did some work for the organization (e.g., organize a local conference or chapter meeting), you can put exactly that (e.g. 'co-organized annual XYZ regional meeting in 2014').

When you have built up a network relevant for the employer through the organization, you might also list your membership.

Otherwise, leave it out.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the target of your résumé

1. If the company is (uninformed) and (uninterested) you get no
   particular advantage for putting that. Then, why putting that?
2. if the company is (uninformed) and (interested) you could win a small advantage by doing so.
3. If the company is (informed) and (uninterested) see case 1
4. If the company is (informed) and (interested) then they will ask you during the interview, and feel deceived when you tell them that this is a contact that they will not be able to take advantage of. So it's a loss on your side and may harm your chances of getting a job.

I cannot see a clear win in putting that, so I would remove it. Maybe being member you went to a conference, or shared some presentations to them, or did something for them. Focus on that instead.